# How to suppress OpenAI API warnings in Python

Tags: python, openai-api

When can I suppress warnings such as:

message='Request to OpenAI API' method=post path=https://api.openai.com/v1/engines/davinci/completions

when I am running OpenAI in python?

Comment: This looks like a response you get from the api and not a warning from python you can suppress.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who comes across this now (March 8, 2023) this has changed to

```
openai.util.logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

Comment: Majors ups to you!!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your Jupyter Notebook or Python script file

```js
import logging
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the OpenAI python package and do requests to GPT-3 for example you will get messages like OP shows (showing the duration of the request for example).

In theory you need to get the base logger and raise its level.
However, it seems like inside the openAI package a specific logger is specified. Therefore you need to load this one and set its level.

The Info-messages will be gone then:

```
openai.util.logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```